# maven does not see existing dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

First of all let me admit that this is a question I see all over the Internet. I have tried many of the solutions I have seen with no luck on my end.
So, I have this maven project

```
  <groupId>com.mycompany.InfoFinder</groupId>
  <artifactId>InfoFinder</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6.4</version>
```

and a different project that depends on the first one.

```
   <groupId>com.mycompany.update</groupId>
   <artifactId>updates</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.44.8</version>
    ....
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.InfoFinder</groupId>
      <artifactId>InfoFinder</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.6.4</version>
    <dependency>
```

When I run mvn clean install -U I get this

```
 .../src/main/java/com/mycompany/Update.java:[3,48] package com.mycompany.companyInfo does not exist
.../src/main/java/eu/com/mycompany/Update.java:[51,36] cannot find symbol....
```

This line refers to the dependency class, which on eclipse I can click on it and it will open the proper file.
If I change my dependency to the older version

```
  <version>1.0.6.4</version>
```

It is working just fine.
I can see the folder under the .m2 folder and I tried deleting it with no difference. I also tried different mvn commands, such as dependency:purge-local-repository clean install in order to clear the cache memory, but still with no luck.

I have tried to update/clear the maven and the java project within the eclipse environment, but that didn't work either.

I should admit that this is not the fist time I see this error, but it usually goes away after a few builds attempts.

Can you tell what I am doing wrong.

PS. The projects builds and runs just fine under the eclipse IDE, so the problem must be on the maven end. Also, since maven doesn't complain when I use the older version of the dependency, that should mean that the problem is on the building of the dependency.

Thanks

---

**EDIT**
I of course first successfully build the first project (lets call it project A) and then the one that depends on it (lets call it project B), and I get the error there.

The pom files of the two projects are as follow
project A

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.InfoFinder</groupId>
  <artifactId>InfoFinder</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6.4</version>
   <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
       <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        
           </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  
       <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
     ...  </repository>
    
     <snapshotRepository>
      ...  </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <dependencies> 
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
    </dependency>     

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.AgeCalculator</groupId>
        <artifactId>AgeCalculator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.linkedbusiness.tool.selenium.imports</groupId>
        <artifactId>seleniumImports</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3-RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.solver</groupId>
        <artifactId>solver</artifactId>
                <version>[1,)</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
</project>
```

project B

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
   <groupId>com.mycompany.update</groupId>
   <artifactId>updates</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.44.8</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>....
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <name>Nexus RELEASE</name>...
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.13.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.Calculator</groupId>
        <artifactId>Calculator</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
   </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.ExtraMetadata</groupId>
            <artifactId>ExtraMetadata</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.InfoFinder</groupId>
            <artifactId>InfoFinder</artifactId>
           <version>1.0.6.4</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>
                                ....Main
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>....
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>...
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: Does your build on plain command line without any issue?

Comment: @khmarbaise no, I get the same result on command line (mvn clean install) as i get using the eclipse commands

Comment: can you please share your both the poms if possible.

Comment: Also, i would try to answer on basis of the information you shared.

If you have two projects X and Y and Y depends on X, then you have to  build X first. So when you do "mvn clean install" to X, it will create the jar in local repo and then you would need to build project Y. Also refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38596946/maven-build-failure-package-does-not-exist

Comment: @P.Sanjay Edited the question with the pom files. Also, I do build project A successfully before going to project B

Comment: Ok Great.  I hope you are not using the wrong jar of project B. Now one question, which jar you are using of your Project B? After Project build B, there would be two jars created in target folder, one with artifact name and another one with "jar-with-dependencies". You have to use jar with "jar-with-dependencies" name as this jar contains all the dependency jars.